# Wrong operator being called

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Here's the problem, I'm trying to overload operator+=() and I think I successfully have done so, but when I call foo += bar the compiler states that I have invalid operands for operator+(). Does anyone know why this might be happening? Example of the code is below:

```
Array& Array::operator+=(Recipe& recipe){ //Adds a Recipe object to Array object and orders
  int i = 0;

  if (size == MAX_RECIPES)
    return;

  while(i!=size && recipe.getName() > recipes[i]->getName()) //Order
    i++;

  for(int j=size; j>i; j--) //Shift to fit new recipe
    recipes[j] = recipes[j-1];
  recipes[i] = &recipe;
  size++;
  return *this;
}


void UImanager::addRecipes(Array *arr){ //Adds multiple Recipe objects to a temporary Array object
  int i;
  cout << endl << "Enter the number of recipes you wish to add: ";
  cin >> i;
  if(i<0)
    return;

  Array *tempArr = new Array;
  while(i){
    Recipe *tempRecipe = new Recipe;
    getRecipeData(tempRecipe);
    tempArr += tempRecipe;
    i--;
  }
```

In essence, the Array class is a collection class for Recipe objects, and the UImanager class is where user interaction takes place.

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please

Comment: Why are you using pointers in your function?  By doing so you have introduced a memory leak.

Comment: If I were to add 1,000 recipes, your `while` loop has introduced 1,000 memory leaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You variable `tempArr` has type `Array *` but you should apply `operator+()` to an object of type `Array` not a pointer (same for recipe):

```
*tempArr += *tempRecipe;
```

Note: if you want to use `operator+()` on a pointer to `Recipe`, you can change parameter to pointer instead of reference, but you cannot do the same with `Array`, as `operator+=()` in this form has to be applied on object. Otherwise you have to call it explicitly:

```
tempArr->operator+=( *tempRecipe );
```

in either case parameter should be `const Recipe &` or `const Recipe *` as you do not expect object to be modified.